# Derivative of complicated function with python

Tags: python, math, numpy

I have a pretty complicated diespersion relation which I want to derive.
Here is the code for the dispersion relation:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

#function definitions. compare following paper eqs. (60) and (61)
#"Hamiltionian formalism for two magnon scattering microwave relaxation:
#Theory and applications"
#Krivosik, Kalarickal, Patton
#JAP 101, 083901 (2007)

def omega(gamma,Bx,By): #resonance frequency
    return gamma*sqrt(Bx*By)

def Bx(B,A,k,mu_0,Ms,Nk): #magnetic field in x-direction
    return B+(2*A/Ms)*k**2+mu_0*Ms*Nk

def By(B,A,k,mu_0,Ms,phi,Nk): #magnetic field in y-direction
    return B+(2*A/Ms)*k**2+mu_0*Ms*(sin(phi)**2)*(1-Nk)

def k(kx,n,w): #k-vektor of spin wave
    return sqrt(kx**2+(n*pi/w)**2)

def Nk(k,d): #Dipole field function
    return (1-exp(-k*d))/(k*d)

def phi(kx,n,w): #angle between k vector and magnetization which points along x-axis
    return arctan(n*pi/(w*kx))

#constants and parameters
gamma=28 #GHz/T
mu_0=4*pi*1e-7 #As/Vm

#range of k-vectors
kx=linspace(0,25000000,1000)

#sample parameters
A=3.5e-12 #J/m
Ms=140000 #A/m
B=0.05 #mT
w=2e-6 #m
d=100e-9 #m

fig=pl.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 6.25), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
font = {'weight' : 'normal', 'size'   : 13}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

n=1
plot(kx/1e6, omega(gamma,Bx(B,A,k(kx,n,w),mu_0,Ms,Nk(k(kx,n,w),d)),By(B,A,k(kx,n,w),mu_0,Ms,phi(kx,n,w),Nk(k(kx,n,w),d))), 'k-')
```

Now I want to derive the function since the slope of the function is of crucial importance for me...

1. Is there an easier way to define the function?
2. For the derivative I need to calculate d_omega/d_kx. I do not need the analytical expression! Which way would you recommend?
3. Should I just take the values of omega and compute manually

   (omega(n+1)-omega(n))/(kx(n+1)-kx(n))

   or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You may not need a symbolic expression for the derivative, but numerical differentiation is susceptible to errors, so my advice is to construct a symbolic expression (via Sympy, let's say) and evaluate that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function gradient, which is implemented in numpy.

The gradient is computed using central differences in the interior and first differences at the boundaries. The returned gradient hence hasthe same shape as the input array.

This is how you can use it to plot the derivative, just copying your example.

```
plot(kx/1e6, gradient(omega(gamma,Bx(B,A,k(kx,n,w),mu_0,Ms,Nk(k(kx,n,w),d)),By(B,A,k(kx,n,w),mu_0,Ms,phi(kx,n,w),Nk(k(kx,n,w),d)))), 'k-')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you use numpy 1.9 (currently dev version) the gradient function uses second order accurate differences on the boundary too so the accuracy is preserved across the whole derivative :) http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html

Comment: That is a nice improvement! ;)

Comment: It seems that this function doesn't deliver the correct values. Probably because the gradient function doesn't know my kx-values. gradient() strongly depends on the number of points.

Comment: That is right, but you can also include the differences as an argument to the gradient function. gradient(func[1:],diff(func)). In this case the result is similar to what you have implemented at your post below, but the values at the edges might be wrong. This can be quite handy if you are using arrays with more than one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways:

1. Numerical approximation (as listed above by others).

   - [numdifftools](https://code.google.com/p/numdifftools/), (just updated to version 0.5) this uses a finite difference approach but keeps track of the numerical error estimate thus giving reliable results i.e. it automatically takes care of mesh size.
2. [Automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation).

   - <s>[numdifftools](https://code.google.com/p/numdifftools/), (just updated to version 0.5)</s>
   - [pyautodiff](https://github.com/LowinData/pyautodiff), very elegant code thanks to Theano and decorators
   - [adol-c](http://autodiff.org/) has a python wrapper
3. Symbolic derivative.

   - [sympy](http://sympy.org/), the classic python symbolic derivative module
   - [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), an iPython-like environment intended as a alternative to Mathematica, built on python.

Both 2 and 3 will be more accurate than numerical derivatives because to preserve accuracy you need to sample the equation over a very fine mesh.

Comment: numdifftools is numerical approximation, not automatic differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html) scipy utility function, that allows to play both with the size of the discretization `dx` and with order of the finite difference scheme, set by default to `3`. This is an example:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
f=lambda kx : omega(gamma,Bx(B,A,k(kx,n,w),mu_0,Ms,Nk(k(kx,n,w),d)),By(B,A,k(kx,n,w),mu_0,Ms,phi(kx,n,w),Nk(k(kx,n,w),d)))
df = derivative(f,kx,dx=kx[1]-kx[0])
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(kx/1e6,f(kx),'b')
bx=ax.twinx()
bx.plot(kx/1e6,df,'r')
bx.grid()
```

[image]

Comment: It seems as this doesn't really work. The derivative of the funktion for kx=0 is 0 and noch 3.1? The gradient tool from delivers the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem

```
#Definitions from above
dispersion =lambda n : omega(gamma,Bx(B,A,k(kx,n,w),mu_0,Ms,Nk(k(kx,n,w),d)),By(B,A,k(kx,n,w),mu_0,Ms,phi(kx,n,w),Nk(k(kx,n,w),d)))
derivative=diff(dispersion(n))/diff(kx)
```